# What are the orange bars on Amazon Music track lists?

Tags: amazon-music, streaming

I've just started listening to Amazon Music.  (I am an Amazon Prime subscriber.)  I've noticed that when I look at a track list for an album, each track has a bar graph indicator with orange bars.  What do they mean?

I've shown an example below.  They are not progress bars, because I have not yet listened to any of the tracks below on Amazon Music.  Nothing happens when you click or hover over the bars with the cursor.

[image: Abbey Road orange bars]

Comment: I gaurntee it's popularity just like iTunes has.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you inspect the source code of the page you will see that the 'id' of that particular bar is :

```
'dmusic_tracklist_popularity_B0191V2IIK'
```

In addition, the 'class' of the column in which it sits is :

```
'PopularityColumn'
```

Which implies that, as Dom said, it's the popularity of the track amongst downloaders.